# Client will not connect to server once launch(args)-Method-call is added to main-Method

Tags: java, javafx, client-server

I want to establish a client-server-connection (with a Javafx Interface on the Clients side) but the Client will not connect to the server. Interestingly, when the launch(args)-Method-Call in the Main-method is commented out, the client will connect to the server.

I'm quite new to Java and especially Javafx and Client-Server-Applications.
The following Code do partially not represent the whole class, I've just left out methods that were not necessary in the context (or at least I think they are unnecessary.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LoginUI loginUI = new LoginUI(primaryStage);
        loginUI.setScene(primaryStage, loginUI.getScene());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        try {
            Client client = new Client(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9376);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //loginUI.getSignUpUI().setSignUpButtonAction(client);
        //my only Instace of LoginUI is in start-Method. How do I pass that to main, since main is static?
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private DataOutputStream outputClient;
    private DataInputStream inputClient;

    public Client(InetAddress ipAddress, int port){
        try {
            this.clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
            this.outputClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.inputClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            outputClient.writeUTF("Client connected on port: " + clientSocket.getPort() + ", with IP: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
        }
        catch(IOException e3){
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
public class Server {

    private ServerSocket skt;
    private volatile boolean serverON;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            this.skt = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.serverON = true;
        }
        catch(IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void serverStart() {
        while (serverON) {
            clientSocket = null;
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + skt.getLocalPort());
            try {
                clientSocket = skt.accept();
                System.out.println("Client has connected: " + clientSocket);

                DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream  dataOut = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Trying to assign Thread to client...");

                Thread thread = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, dataIn, dataOut);
                thread.start();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ServerMain.java**

```
public class ServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server server = new Server(9376);
        server.serverStart();
    }
}
```

I don't get any error (at least initially, errors still occur later when using the UI in specific ways) when the launch()-call is not commented out, the client just won't connect to the server.

Comment: When you call launch it does into the application loop and the code below is never hit. You probably wnt to move the client code into the application class and not the main method.

Comment: Actually `launch` does return, but only after the JavaFX toolkit has been shut down never to be started again during this run of the program...

Comment: As the other comments pointed out, the call to `launch` does not return until the JavaFX runtime exits. You need to move your client-connect code somewhere else. One option, if you want to connect "before" JavaFX starts, is to move that code into `Application#init()` (override the method in `Main`). If connecting should happen concurrently, you need to use another thread.

Comment: Oh I see. I've now moved the Initialization of my Client in the init-Method and than it works! Thank you so much for your input, everyone! @Slaw just out of curiosity, how would I go about using another thread in this case?

Comment: Thanks fabian and @Slaw, I should have been more specific but thought that the main method comment/functionality was implied.